# Insert a Multidimensional Array into a MYSQL Database

Tags: php

I have an array which is multidimensional. The array is similar to the one below:

```
  Array => [link] => http://www.theqlick.com
  => [title] => The Qlick
  => [description] A great way to connect to the Internet
  => [keywords] Search Engine, The Qlick, Noah Smith
```

and

```
  Array => [link] => http://www.google.com

  => [title] => Google
  => [description] A great search engine
  => [keywords] Google, the web, search engine
```

And for each array similar to the two above, i want it to be 1 row. I have a title, keywords, descriptions and url fields for them to be inputted. But they don't seem to be inputted into the database. Any ideas??

```
$data = array();
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $output = array(
        "title"       => Titles($link), 
        "link"        => $link,
        "description" => getMetas($link),
        "keywords" => getKeywords($link) 
    );

    if (empty($output["description"])){ 
        $output["description"] = getWord($link);
    }
    $data[] = $output;
}

print_r($data);  

mysql_query("INSERT INTO scan (title, url, description, keywords) VALUES ('".implode("'),('",$data)."')");

if (!mysql_query()) {
    echo "woops";
}

mysql_close($connect);
```

Comment: cringe! Start by learning SQL, then move to mysqli or pdo so that you can use prepared statements

Comment: Do you mean to have mysql_error() in the last if statement?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).